# Using 27MHz car with 49MHz remote control

Tags: arduino, rf, frequency, remote-control, transmitter

I managed to do something like this guy [here](http://forefront.io/a/hacking-9-buck-remote-controlled-car-with-arduino), but after I connected the Arduino to the `49MHz` remote control, I figured out that I have another car which works on `27MHz`, so I would like to ask is there any way with which I can control the `27MHz` car with `49MHz` controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: No.

Long answer: No, because the transmitter and receiver have to be tuned to the same frequency. You can't listen to Kool108 FM by tuning your radio to the frequency of 93X FM.

It is unlikely that a 9 dollar toy is designed to make it easilly retunable.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I thought it could be possible because this guy said: http://i.imgur.com/ixfpQfn.png